# Can I use Oracle API Gateway with WSO2 API Manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

Reason of using WSO2 is to have api management capabilities which existing Oracle Gateway doesnot have.
Flow will be like-->Oracle API Gateway-->WSO2 API Manager-->Backend Service

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use it. You have to pass the access token from Oracle API Gateway to WSO2 API Manager while invoking the API. There is no restriction other than that.

Comment: Kugathasan Thanks.Also want to know like can I use WSO2 APIM as a Facade layer or I need combination of WSO2 APIM+WSO2 ESB.

Comment: No, You can use API Manager without WSO2 ESB. Both are sharing similar functionalities.

Comment: @Bistu, Accept the answer if it's satify you.

Comment: Yes thanks for the answers,hope that WSO2 can do minimal transformation and mediation that WSO2 ESB does.